# How to make "word images" from atomic symbols of the table of elements, as in Periodle

Tags: tikz-pgf

One of the harder offshoots of [Wordle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html) is a game called [Periodle](https://heptaveegesimal.com/2022/periodle). In this version you make words from the atomic symbols of [the periodic table of elements](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/periodic-table/). As in

[image]

Here the request is to make it possible for a chemistry teacher to print one word or a table of such word images.
The teacher supplies the word or the list of words, how it spells via the atomic symbols, and its meaning.
So, the list consists of entries such as:

P-H-Y-Si-Cs : Physics is a branch of science

Your program outputs a table consisting of word images. With the addition of the optional  definition underneath or above the image. (The above picture comes from [(Source)](https://sciencenotes.org/list-words-made-periodic-table-element-symbols/), you choose your style).

The general input to the program is a list of each atomic symbol with its atomic number, the name of the element, and some color scheme number.
As in

Ac, 89, Actinium, 6

or it could be just a question mark, in case the teacher wants to leave out some symbols and then ask students to guess it.

Other teachers can also make use of the Periodle game for class activity. A restriction in the Periodle is that all words are 5 symbols long (and 6-10 letters). For helping kids to play this rather hard game the teacher might want to present some words in a table with C columns (probably C=3 or 4 is a good choice). This will be a nice feature as it allows kids to scan many words at once.

The following is an alphabetic list of the elements (I am not a chemist and hopefully I have not made a mistake in making the list). The color scheme is according to the traditional ``chemical group block'', but a teacher might consider another basis for coloring the elements. The color designation of blocks here are

1=Nonmetal, 2=Alkali Metal, 3=Alkaline Earth Metal, 4=Transition Metal, 5=Lanthanide, 6=Actinide, 7=Metalloid, 8=Post-Transition Metal, 9=Halogen, 10=Noble Gas

(Edit: The entries for Krypton and Tennessine were corrected.)

Ac, 89, Actinium, 6

Ag, 47, Silver, 4

Al, 13, Aluminum, 4

Am, 95, Americium, 6

Ar, 18, Argon, 10

As, 33, Arsenic, 7

At, 85, Astatine, 9

Au, 79, Gold, 4

B, 5, Boron, 7

Ba, 56, Barium, 3

Be, 4, Beryllium, 4

Bh, 107, Bohrium, 4

Bi, 83, Bismuth, 8

Bk, 97, Berkelium, 6

Br, 35, Bromine, 9

C, 6, Carbon, 1

Ca, 20, Calcium, 3

Cd, 48, Cadmium, 4

Ce, 58, Cerium, 5

Cf, 98, Californium, 6

Cl, 17, Chlorine, 9

Cm, 96, Curium, 6

Cn, 112, Copernicium, 4

Co, 27, Cobalt, 4

Cr, 24, Chromium, 4

Cs, 55, Cesium, 2

Cu, 29, Copper, 4

Db, 105, Dubnium, 4

Ds, 110, Darmstadtium, 4

Dy, 66, Dysprosium, 5

Er, 68, Erbium, 5

Es, 99, Einsteinium, 6

Eu, 63, Europium, 5

F, 9, Fluorine, 9

Fe, 26, Iron, 3

Fl, 114, Flerovium, 8

Fm, 100, Fermium, 6

Fr, 87, Francium, 2

Ga, 31, Gallium, 8

Gd, 64, Gadolinium, 5

Ge, 32, Germanium, 7

H, 1 , Hydrogen, 1

He, 2, Helium, 10

Hf, 72, Hafnium, 4

Hg, 80, Mercury, 4

Ho, 67, Holmium, 5

Hs, 108, Hassium, 4

I, 53, Iodine, 9

In, 49, Indium, 8

Ir, 77, Iridium, 4

K, 19, Potassium, 2

Kr, 36, Krypton, 10

La, 57, Lanthanum, 5

Li, 3, Lithium, 2

Lr, 103, Lawrencium, 6

Lu, 71, Lutetium, 5

Lv, 116, Livermorium, 8

Md, 101, Mendelevium, 6

Mg, 12, Magnesium, 3

Mn, 25, Manganese, 4

Mo, 42, Molybdenum, 4

Ms, 115, Moscovium, 8

Mt, 109, Meitnerium, 4

N, 7, Nitrogen, 1

Na, 11, Sodium, 2

Nb, 41, Niobium, 4

Nd, 60, Neodymium, 5

Ne, 10, Neon, 10

Nh, 113, Nihonium, 8

Ni, 28, Nickel, 4

No, 102, Nobelium, 6

Np, 93, Neptunium, 6

O, 8, Oxygen, 1

Og, 118, Oganesson, 10

Os, 76, Osmium, 4

P, 15, Phosphorus, 1

Pa, 91, Protactinium, 6

Pb, 82, Lead, 8

Pd, 46, Palladium, 4

Pm, 61, Promethium, 5

Po, 84, Polonium, 7

Pr, 59, Praseodymium, 5

Pt, 78, Platinum, 4

Pu, 94, Plutonium, 6

Ra, 88, Radium, 2

Rb, 37, Rubidium, 2

Re, 75, Rhenium, 4

Rf, 104, Rutherfordium, 4

Rg, 111, Roentgenium, 4

Rh, 45, Rhodium, 4

Rn, 86, Radon, 10

Ru, 44, Ruthenium, 4

S, 16, Sulfur, 1

Sb, 51, Antimony, 7

Sc, 21, Scandium, 4

Se, 34, Selenium, 1

Sg, 106, Seaborgium, 4

Si, 14, Silicon, 7

Sm, 62, Samarium, 5

Sn, 50, Tin, 8

Sr, 38, Strontium, 3

Ta, 73, Tantalum, 4

Tb, 65, Terbium, 5

Tc, 43, Technetium, 4

Te, 52, Tellurium, 7

Th, 90, Thorium, 6

Ti, 22, Titanium, 4

Tl, 81, Thallium, 8

Tm, 69, Thulium, 5

Ts, 117, Tennessine, 9

U, 92, Uranium, 6

V, 23, Vanadium, 4

W, 74, Tungsten, 4

Xe, 54, Xenon, 10

Y, 39, Yttrium, 4

Yb, 70, Ytterbium, 5

Zn, 30, Zinc, 4

Zr, 40, Zirconium, 4

Comment: I think you're getting close votes because this does read like a "do this for me" problem.

Comment: @Teepeemm ,  I think the game has educational value. It is the only science-based word game I know. The resulting program is of use to teachers. They have been doing "words made out of images or pieces" long before the game. The game is hard to play, even with the mastery of the periodic table. The purists may play it as is at their own peril but most need some visual help. I am not a TeX programmer, hence the call on the experts for help. The choices as I saw it were: (1) not have this page, (2) I ask "can you do it?".

Comment: The game may have educational value, but the game is not about (La)TeX as far as I understand it. On the other hand, *this site* is about (La)TeX and not about chemistry. So,  asking how to create such images with (La)TeX is not off-topic on this site, but your quesstion could have been a bit more focused on this aspect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Updated Solution:

The whole thing is now wrapped into a macro `\periodle` that takes a comma-separated list of element symbols. So

```
\periodle{P,H,Y,Si,Cs}

\periodle{La,Te,Xe,Rf,O,Re,V,Er}
```

Produces

[image]

If you include a symbol that is not the symbol of an element, a gray `?` tile will appear. The color is controled with `\definecolor{unk}{rgb}{.3,.3,.3}`

```
\periodle{La,Te,Xe,Rf,O,Re,V,Er,?}
```

[image]

You can add elements to `\elementlist` using the syntax `<symbol>/<number>/<name>/<color>`. For example, `Lx/314/Latex/pink`.

The color values are approximated from the Periodle website:

[image]

Here is the code including the lengthy `\elementlist`. Note there were a few errors I fixed (uncapitalized Kr, misspelled Tennessine). There may be others.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\newcommand{\elementlist}{Ac/89/Actinium/6,Ag/47/Silver/4,Al/13/Aluminum/4,Am/95/Americium/6,Ar/18/Argon/10,As/33/Arsenic/7,At/85/Astatine/9,Au/79/Gold/4,B/5/Boron/7,Ba/56/Barium/3,Be/4/Beryllium/4,Bh/107/Bohrium/4,Bi/83/Bismuth/8,Bk/97/Berkelium/6,Br/35/Bromine/9,C/6/Carbon/1,Ca/20/Calcium/3,Cd/48/Cadmium/4,Ce/58/Cerium/5,Cf/98/Californium/6,Cl/17/Chlorine/9,Cm/96/Curium/6,Cn/112/Copernicium/4,Co/27/Cobalt/4,Cr/24/Chromium/4,Cs/55/Cesium/2,Cu/29/Copper/4,Db/105/Dubnium/4,Ds/110/Darmstadtium/4,Dy/66/Dysprosium/5,Er/68/Erbium/5,Es/99/Einsteinium/6,Eu/63/Europium/5,F/9/Fluorine/9,Fe/26/Iron/3,Fl/114/Flerovium/8,Fm/100/Fermium/6,Fr/87/Francium/2,Ga/31/Gallium/8,Gd/64/Gadolinium/5,Ge/32/Germanium/7,H/1/Hydrogen/1,He/2/Helium/10,Hf/72/Hafnium/4,Hg/80/Mercury/4,Ho/67/Holmium/5,Hs/108/Hassium/4,I/53/Iodine/9,In/49/Indium/8,Ir/77/Iridium/4,K/19/Potassium/2,Kr/36/Krypton/10,La/57/Lanthanum/5,Li/3/Lithium/2,Lr/103/Lawrencium/6,Lu/71/Lutetium/5,Lv/116/Livermorium/8,Md/101/Mendelevium/6,Mg/12/Magnesium/3,Mn/25/Manganese/4,Mo/42/Molybdenum/4,Ms/115/Moscovium/8,Mt/109/Meitnerium/4,N/7/Nitrogen/1,Na/11/Sodium/2,Nb/41/Niobium/4,Nd/60/Neodymium/5,Ne/10/Neon/10,Nh/113/Nihonium/8,Ni/28/Nickel/4,No/102/Nobelium/6,Np/93/Neptunium/6,O/8/Oxygen/1,Og/118/Oganesson/10,Os/76/Osmium/4,P/15/Phosphorus/1,Pa/91/Protactinium/6,Pb/82/Lead/8,Pd/46/Palladium/4,Pm/61/Promethium/5,Po/84/Polonium/7,Pr/59/Praseodymium/5,Pt/78/Platinum/4,Pu/94/Plutonium/6,Ra/88/Radium/2,Rb/37/Rubidium/2,Re/75/Rhenium/4,Rf/104/Rutherfordium/4,Rg/111/Roentgenium/4,Rh/45/Rhodium/4,Rn/86/Radon/10,Ru/44/Ruthenium/4,S/16/Sulfur/1,Sb/51/Antimony/7,Sc/21/Scandium/4,Se/34/Selenium/1,Sg/106/Seaborgium/4,Si/14/Silicon/7,Sm/62/Samarium/5,Sn/50/Tin/8,Sr/38/Strontium/3,Ta/73/Tantalum/4,Tb/65/Terbium/5,Tc/43/Technetium/4,Te/52/Tellurium/7,Th/90/Thorium/6,Ti/22/Titanium/4,Tl/81/Thallium/8,Tm/69/Thulium/5,Ts/117/Tennessine/9,U/92/Uranium/6,V/23/Vanadium/4,W/74/Tungsten/4,Xe/54/Xenon/10,Y/39/Yttrium/4,Yb/70/Ytterbium/5,Zn/30/Zinc/4,Zr/40/Zirconium/4}

\definecolor{1}{rgb}{0.01, 0.28, 1.00}
\definecolor{2}{rgb}{1.00, 0.03, 0.00}
\definecolor{3}{rgb}{1.00, 0.49, 0.00}
\definecolor{4}{rgb}{0.99, 0.93, 0.00}
\definecolor{5}{rgb}{0.80, 0.00, 0.80}
\definecolor{6}{rgb}{1.00, 0.08, 0.58}
\definecolor{7}{rgb}{0.00, 0.75, 1.00}
\definecolor{8}{rgb}{0.20, 0.80, 0.20}
\definecolor{9}{rgb}{0.62, 0.00, 1.00}
\definecolor{10}{rgb}{0.41, 0.00, 0.66}
\definecolor{unk}{rgb}{.3,.3,.3}

\newcommand{\periodle}[1]{\tikz[start chain, node distance=0mm]{\foreach \elem in {#1}{\xdef\ll{?}\xdef\nn{}\xdef\mm{}\xdef\cc{unk}
    \foreach \l/\n/\m/\c in \elementlist{\ifthenelse{\equal{\l}{\elem}}{\xdef\ll{\l}\xdef\nn{\n}\xdef\mm{\m}\xdef\cc{\c}}{}}
    \node[on chain, line width=.5mm, draw=gray, shade, left color=\cc, right color=white, shading angle=210, minimum size=1cm, font=\sffamily\bfseries](B){\ll};
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries, transform shape,scale=.4] at ([yshift=-3mm]B){\nn};
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries, transform shape,scale=.4] at ([yshift=3mm]B){\mm};
}}}


\begin{document}

\periodle{P,H,Y,Si,Cs}

\periodle{La,Te,Xe,Rf,O,Re,V,Er,?}

\end{document}
```

### Old Solution:

OK. This is a bit silly, but here is a macro `\periodle` that takes a comma-separated list as input. Each entry should have the form `<symbol>/<name>/<number>/<color>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0.68, 0.87, 0.68}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0.99, 0.99, 0.59}
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.74, 0.83, 0.99}
\definecolor{c4}{rgb}{0.81, 0.59, 0.86}

\newcommand{\periodle}[1]{\tikz[start chain, node distance=0mm]{\foreach \l/\n/\m/\c in {#1}{
    \node[on chain, line width=.5mm, draw=gray, shade, left color=\c, right color=white, shading angle=210, minimum size=1cm, font=\sffamily\bfseries](B){\l};
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries, transform shape,scale=.4] at ([yshift=-3mm]B){\n};
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries, transform shape,scale=.5] at ([yshift=3mm]B){\m};
}}}

\begin{document}

\periodle{Lx/Latexium/201/c1,Xt/Xetexium/202/c2,Mp/Metapostium/203/c3,L/Luanium/204/c4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could store the data in an expl3 prop so that all you needed were the elements.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: good idea. I’ll get around to it eventually…

Answer (score 5):

[image]This is thanks to Sandy G.'s answer. It is the periodic table in alphabetic order of symbols. It is intended to help teachers who want to make a classroom activity or students who want to solve a related puzzle.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\definecolor{1}{rgb}{0.68, 0.87, 0.68}
\definecolor{2}{rgb}{0.99, 0.99, 0.59}
\definecolor{3}{rgb}{0.74, 0.83, 0.99}
\definecolor{4}{rgb}{0.81, 0.59, 0.86}
\definecolor{5}{rgb}{0.77, 0.32, 0.45}
\definecolor{6}{rgb}{0.81, 0.63, 0.44}
\definecolor{7}{rgb}{0.66, 0.83, 0.99}
\definecolor{8}{rgb}{0.99, 0.59, 0.86}
\definecolor{9}{rgb}{0.44, 0.32, 0.45}
\definecolor{10}{rgb}{0.55, 0.63, 0.44}
\definecolor{11}{rgb}{0.66, 0.77, 0.88}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\null 
\vskip -.5in

\newcommand{\periodle}[1]{\tikz[start chain, node distance=0mm]{\foreach \l/\m/\n/\c in {#1}{
%   \node[on chain, line width=.5mm, draw=gray, fill=\c, minimum size=1cm, font=\sffamily\bfseries](B){\l};
\node[on chain, line width=.5mm, draw=gray, shade, left color=\c, right color=white, shading angle=210, minimum size=1cm, font=\sffamily\bfseries](B){\l};
\node[font=\sffamily\bfseries, transform shape,scale=.4] at ([yshift=-3mm]B){\n};
\node[font=\sffamily\bfseries, transform shape,scale=.4] at ([yshift=3mm]B){\m};
}}}

\begin{document}
\periodle{
Ac/89/Actinium/6,
Ag/47/Silver/4,
Al/13/Aluminum/4,
Am/95/Americium/6,
Ar/18/Argon/10,
As/33/Arsenic/7,
At/85/Astatine/9,
Au/79/Gold/4}

\periodle{
B/5/Boron/7,
Ba/56/Barium/3,
Be/4/Beryllium/4,
Bh/107/Bohrium/4,
Bi/83/Bismuth/8,
Bk/97/Berkelium/6,
Br/35/Bromine/9}

\periodle{
C/6/Carbon/1,
Ca/20/Calcium/3,
Cd/48/Cadmium/4,
Ce/58/Cerium/5,
Cf/98/Californium/6,
Cl/17/Chlorine/9,
Cm/96/Curium/6,
Cn/112/Copernicium/4,
Co/27/Cobalt/4,
Cr/24/Chromium/4,
Cs/55/Cesium/2,
Cu/29/Copper/4}

\periodle{
Db/105/Dubnium/4,
Ds/110/Darmstadtium/4,
Dy/66/Dysprosium/5}

\periodle{
Er/68/Erbium/5,
Es/99/Einsteinium/6,
Eu/63/Europium/5}

\periodle{
F/9/Fluorine/9,
Fe/26/Iron/3,
Fl/114/Flerovium/8,
Fm/100/Fermium/6,
Fr/87/Francium/2}

\periodle{
Ga/31/Gallium/8,
Gd/64/Gadolinium/5,
Ge/32/Germanium/7}

\periodle{
H/1/Hydrogen/1,
He/2/Helium/10,
Hf/72/Hafnium/4,
Hg/80/Mercury/4,
Ho/67/Holmium/5,
Hs/108/Hassium/4}

\periodle{
I/53/Iodine/9,
In/49/Indium/8,
Ir/77/Iridium/4}

\periodle{
K/19/Potassium/2,
kr/36/Krypton/10}

\periodle{
La/57/Lanthanum/5,
Li/3/Lithium/2,
Lr/103/Lawrencium/6,
Lu/71/Lutetium/5,
Lv/116/Livermorium/8}

\periodle{
Md/101/Mendelevium/6,
Mg/12/Magnesium/3,
Mn/25/Manganese/4,
Mo/42/Molybdenum/4,
Ms/115/Moscovium/8,
Mt/109/Meitnerium/4}

\periodle{
N/7/Nitrogen/1,
Na/11/Sodium/2,
Nb/41/Niobium/4,
Nd/60/Neodymium/5,
Ne/10/Neon/10,
Nh/113/Nihonium/8,
Ni/28/Nickel/4,
No/102/Nobelium/6,
Np/93/Neptunium/6}

\periodle{
O/8/Oxygen/1,
Og/118/Oganesson/10,
Os/76/Osmium/4}

\periodle{
P/15/Phosphorus/1,
Pa/91/Protactinium/6,
Pb/82/Lead/8,
Pd/46/Palladium/4,
Pm/61/Promethium/5,
Po/84/Polonium/7,
Pr/59/Praseodymium/5,
Pt/78/Platinum/4,
Pu/94/Plutonium/6}

\periodle{
Ra/88/Radium/2,
Rb/37/Rubidium/2,
Re/75/Rhenium/4,
Rf/104/Rutherfordium/4,
Rg/111/Roentgenium/4,
Rh/45/Rhodium/4,
Rn/86/Radon/10,
Ru/44/Ruthenium/4}

\periodle{
S/16/Sulfur/1,
Sb/51/Antimony/7,
Sc/21/Scandium/4,
Se/34/Selenium/1,
Sg/106/Seaborgium/4,
Si/14/Silicon/7,
Sm/62/Samarium/5,
Sn/50/Tin/8,
Sr/38/Strontium/3}

\periodle{
Ta/73/Tantalum/4,
Tb/65/Terbium/5,
Tc/43/Technetium/4,
Te/52/Tellurium/7,
Th/90/Thorium/6,
Ti/22/Titanium/4,
Tl/81/Thallium/8,
Tm/69/Thulium/5,
Ts/117/Tennesineum/9}

\periodle{
U/92/Uranium/6,
V/23/Vanadium/4,
W/74/Tungsten/4,
Xe/54/Xenon/10,
Y/39/Yttrium/4,
Yb/70/Ytterbium/5,
Zn/30/Zinc/4,
Zr/40/Zirconium/4,
?/?/?/11}

\end{document}
```